# Regex for date not working for 29-Feb

Tags: asp.net, regex, date

I use to following Regex for validating a Date field:

> ^(?:((31 (Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec))|((([0-2]\d)|30)
>   (Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))|(([01]\d|2[0-8])
>   Feb))|(29-Feb(?=
>   ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))
>   ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$

The problem here is that it does not allow the Value "29 Feb 2016" and gives an error message.

What could be possible wrong with the expression that it does not allow the date?

Kindly help.
Appreciate your time. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out guys.
Instead of "29-Feb" it should have been "29 Feb".

Apologies for the silliness.
Thanks a ton for your indulgence.